How to do i get the parent node with conditions on child nodes?
I have the below xml:
I am trying to create AFP and PDF using apacheFOP.
                   <Data>
                    <product>
                    <attribute>
                        <name>NUMMER</name>
                        <actionType>RM</actionType>
                        <actionReason>DISCN</actionReason>
                        <value>0</value>
                    </attribute>
                    <attribute>
                        <name>NUMMER</name>
                        <actionType>RM</actionType>
                        <actionReason>DISCN</actionReason>
                        <value>12345</value>
                    </attribute>
                    <attribute>
                        <name>RETURN</name>
                        <actionType>RM</actionType>
                        <actionReason>DISCN</actionReason>
                        <value>00</value>
                        <valueDescription>NO</valueDescription>
                    </attribute>
                    <attribute>
                        <name>ADRESS</name>
                        <actionType>RM</actionType>
                        <actionReason>DISCN</actionReason>
                        <value>4</value>
                        <valueDescription>ABC</valueDescription>
                    </attribute>
                   </product>
                  </Data>

I need to write a check if attribute/name = 'NUMMER' and attribute/value != 0.
I tried the below approaches but none work:
 <xsl:when test="Data/product/attribute[name='NUMMER' and value!='0']"></xsl:when>

 <xsl:when test="Data/product/attribute[name='NUMMER' and not(value='0')]"></xsl:when>

Basically i do not want to generate any AFP/PDF if the above condition exists. So i have a discard logic in my project where in i specify these conditions and tell not to do anything. Here is the actual piece of code which i tried:
<xsl:when test="Data/product/attribute[name='NUMMER' and value!=0]">
    <!-- No details to print -->
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
 <!--Here i have a logic to call the main template which will produce the document for me-->
</xsl:otherwise>

It doesnt enter the when case and rather produces the document which i do not want.

Well, what kind of comparison do you want to make, a numerical one on 0 or a string on '0' and/or on '00'?

And also please consider to explain which result you expect and which one you get if approaches don't "work".

I have updated the question. I should be able to get the  with  !=0

Does an xsl:if in your opinion get or fetch a node so that you see it in the transformation result? Please take your time to post minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT code and wanted and current result. So far it is not clear in which context you have the xsl:if or where you expect to get or fetch some attribute element.

For instance, one inconsistency between your XML sample with a Product element and your XPath expressions is that in the XPath you use a lower case product.

Hi Martin. Thanks for you inputs. I have corrected and reframed the question.

Try something like:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <result>
        <xsl:copy-of select="product/attribute[name='NUMMER' and number(value) ne 0]"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

You can see it working here.

You can see it working in the link above.

You have failed again to produce a simple XSLT sample that allows us to reproduce the problem, if I take your snippet and morph it into a full template
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="Data/product/attribute[name='NUMMER' and value!=0]">
          <xsl:comment>No details</xsl:comment>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:comment>Main template</xsl:comment>
      </xsl:otherwise>        
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

and wrap that into an xsl:stylesheet element and run it against your sample XML the output is <!--No details--> so your condition seems to do its job.
